# Java: HtmlUnit efficiency relacing PHP CURL?

Tags: java, php, http, curl, htmlunit

I have a spider class which on a user request spiders websites for content. Each search results in loading about 30 websites, spidering them for the information and then standardizing this information.

I have written this in PHP using CURL, since PHP is lacking multitasking I would like to switch to Java (I am aware of the multi process curl which does not suit my demand). I need a http client which can POST/GET, receive and set cookies as well as modify HTTP headers.

I have found HtmlUnit which seems nifty but also exceeds my demand, and since the package is relatively big and I will have many hundread requests a minute I don't want to have an overkill solution slowing down my servers.

Do you think this would be an issue and do you have other suggestions to replace CURL in Java? Should I use the Java CURL binding? **This is a question of** efficiency and server load.

Comment: I have tested the efficiency:
4) Java/HTMLUnit 6,2 Seconds
3) Java/Apache_HTTPClient 5,3 Seconds
2) PHP/CURL 4,92 Secods
1) Java/Jsoup 1,8 Seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps take a look at [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) ?

You can create a HttpClient per thread and use that to do your requests

```
while (running) {

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet GET = new HttpGet("mydomain.com/path.html");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(GET);
// do stuff with response

}
```

Even better, if you re-use the HttpClient between requests, it will remember the cookies sent back on previous responses, and automatically apply them to your next request. In that sense a single HttpClient models a http conversation.

So if you did

```
 client.execute(GET1);
  // cookies received in response
  client.execute(GET2);
  // the second get will send the cookies back received from GET1 response.
```

You could then take a look at Java's ExecutorService that will make it easy to place spider jobs and have multiple threads running.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you will need to evaluate potential solutions to see what best suits your need.

HtmlUnit offers a rich Api, for parsing web pages, and finding and evaluating elements on the page.

A simpler solution would be to simply use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (which HtmlUnit uses under the hood). This would simply download the entire page and return it as a OutputStream or String. You can then use regular expressions to find links etc. probably more like you are doing currently with curl.

Answer (score 1):

try http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/ 
simple and efficient solution when you don t need javascript.